# Poor word choice

Tags: discussion

It occurred to me that 'follower' is used to describe subscribers of a tag.

This means that `Jesus` has currently two followers; the same holds for `God`, `Adam-and-Eve`, et cetera. Shouldn't this be changed? ;)

[image: Followers for tag 'Jesus']

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I remember this being the source of some amusement in chat early on as new tags were getting added for the first time. The person who was the first follower must have had serious doubts about their religious affiliation!

However, I think it should be taken as nothing more than that ... an amusing linguistic coincidence. The word follower is standard terminology in the computer world for RSS feeds and twitter streams. It is also standard usage in the religious world. However as with any aspect of understanding language, *context is king*! I don't think it's unreasonable at all to expect readers to understand based on the context a word appears in what it must mean. On the flip side, I do think it would be unreasonable to expect the SE programming staff to wire up special exceptions to standard wording that would ultimatly confuse the issue. The software stack is unified across all sites and exceptions tend to break more things than they fix.

Comment: Not to mention "Loading Christianity // Just a second..." message that comes up when you open up the main chat. :P

Comment: or "do you want to leave Christianity" when you exit the chat room...

Comment: Could we make my favourite phrase a slogan on this site? *Words have different meanings in different contexts.*

Comment: @TRiG heh; not just words, either. A fun example I saw recently "I didn't say she stole my money" - 7 words, and means 7 completely different things depending on which is stressed.